# RoboCopy failing when using passed parameters for Options

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a wrapper for RoboCopy, and having trouble with (it seems) the passed parameters. I can make RoboCopy work if I define the options in the function, but options that are passed in cause RoboCopy to fail. But, if I compare the passed in options to the locally defined ones, it looks as if they are in fact the same. When I run the code below, the first RoboCopy using the passed in parameters gets both Files and Options wring, showing this and failing with an error about the path.

```
Files : 
Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
```

But the second one properly shows

```
Files : *.xml
Options : /FFT /S /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /LEV:1 /MT:8 /R:10 /W:5
```

And it mirrors correctly.
But, all the Ifs at the end return YES.

```
function Invoke-PxMirror {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [String]$source,
        [String]$destination,
        [String]$copyOptions,
        [String]$selectionOptions,
        [String]$retryOptions,
        [String]$logFile,
        [String]$logOptions
    )

    if ($copyOptions) {
        $copyOptions = $copyOptions.Split()
    }
    if ($selectionOptions) {
        $selectionOptions = $selectionOptions.Split()
    }
    if ($retryOptions) {
        $retryOptions = $retryOptions.Split()
    }
    if ($logFile) {
        $logFile = "/log:$logFile"
    }
    if ($logOptions) {
        $logOptions = $logOptions.Split()
    }

    $sourceX = '\\Mac\Px\Support\Px Tools\Recipe Validation'
    $destinationX = "$env:ProgramData\PragmaticPraxis"
    $copyOptionsX = '/mir /lev:1 /copy:dat /mt'
    $selectionOptionsX = '*.xml /fft'
    $retryOptionsX = '/r:10 /w:5'
    $logFileX = "$env:temp\PxAssets.log"
    $logOptionsX = '/njh /ns /nc /np'

    $copyOptionsX = $copyOptionsX.Split()
    $selectionOptionsX = $selectionOptionsX.Split()
    $retryOptionsX = $retryOptionsX.Split()
    $logFileX = "/log:$logFileX"
    $logOptionsX = $logOptionsX.Split()

    &RoboCopy $source $destination $copyOptions $selectionOptions $retryOptions
    &RoboCopy $sourceX $destinationX $copyOptionsX $selectionOptionsX $retryOptionsX


    if ($copyOptions -eq $copyOptionsX) {
        Write-host "copyOptions YES"
    } else {
        Write-host "copyOptions NO"
    }
    if ($selectionOptions -eq $selectionOptionsX) {
        Write-host "selectionOptions YES"
    } else {
        Write-host "selectionOptions NO"
    }
    if ($retryOptions -eq $retryOptionsX) {
        Write-host "retryOptions YES"
    } else {
        Write-host "retryOptions NO"
    }
    if ($logFile -eq $logFileX) {
        Write-host "logFile YES"
    } else {
        Write-host "logFile NO"
    }
    if ($logOptions -eq $logOptionsX) {
        Write-host "logOptions YES"
    } else {
        Write-host "logOptions NO"
    }

}



$mirrorParameters = @{
    source = '\\Mac\Px\Support\Px Tools\Recipe Validation'
    destination = "$env:ProgramData\PragmaticPraxis"
    copyOptions = '/mir /lev:1 /copy:dat /mt'
    selectionOptions = '*.xml /fft'
    retryOptions = '/r:10 /w:5'
    logFile = "$env:temp\PxAssets.log"
    logOptions = '/njh /ns /nc /np'
}
Invoke-PxMirror @mirrorParameters
```

UPDATE:
So yeah, changing variable type (from a string to an array of strings) isn't such a good idea. I suspect I don't really need to specify a string for the revised $logFile, but the rest seems right. Certainly it works, though "works" isn't enough to qualify as "right".

```
function Invoke-PxMirror {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$source,
        [string]$destination,
        [string]$copyOptionsString,
        [string]$selectionOptionsString,
        [string]$retryOptionsString,
        [string]$logFile,
        [string]$logOptionsString
    )

    if ($copyOptionsString) {
        [string[]]$copyOptions = $copyOptionsString.Split(" ")
    }
    if ($selectionOptionsString) {
        [string[]]$selectionOptions = $selectionOptionsString.Split()
    }
    if ($retryOptionsString) {
        [string[]]$retryOptions = $retryOptionsString.Split()
    }
    if ($logFile) {
        [string]$logFile = "/log:$logFile"
    }
    if ($logOptionsString) {
        [string[]]$logOptions = $logOptionsString.Split()
    }

    &RoboCopy $source $destination $copyOptions $selectionOptions $retryOptions

$invokeMirror
}



$mirrorParameters = @{
    source = '\\Mac\Px\Support\Px Tools\Recipe Validation'
    destination = "$env:ProgramData\PragmaticPraxis"
    copyOptions = '/mir /lev:1 /copy:dat /mt'
    selectionOptions = '*.xml /fft'
    retryOptions = '/r:10 /w:5'
    logFile = "$env:temp\PxAssets.log"
    logOptions = '/njh /ns /nc /np'
}
Invoke-PxMirror @mirrorParameters
```

Comment: see the answer with 18+ votes...use arrays...and an element for each option...https://serverfault.com/questions/129098/how-to-get-robocopy-running-in-powershell

Comment: I found that, which is why I am doing the .Split(), to make each group of options an array. The issue is that this technique works fine with locally defined parameters, but not the passed parameters, and I need the passed parameters.

Comment: Compare `$copyOptions.GetType()` vs `$copyOptionsX.GetType()`.

Comment: Your assignments/Split() at the top are not creating arrays...debug in ISE and see this.  If you don't force the types to [String] for params, or use other variables, your code would probably give the results you want.

Comment: Kory, just removing the [String] in the param didn't fix it. But, using totally different variables did. Which is likely better practice anyway. Reusing a variable name when it also changes type seems like an appropriate thing to do at the command line, but in a PS based program it's better to be less dynamic with typing perhaps.